# Differentiability of $f(x) = e^{-(x+2)}\sqrt{x+1}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

My students are required to study the set of differentiability of 
$$f(x) = e^{-(x+2)}\sqrt{x+1}. $$
It is of course defined in $[-1, +\infty)$ and differentiable in $(-1, +\infty)$.
They say that it is not derivable in $x=-1$ because the limit is $+\infty$, I say that it makes no sense to require for differentiability at borders, even if the limit is finite. Who is right?

They also say that $-1$ is not a local minimum because there is no interval, since $f$ is not defined for $x<-1$. I argue it is a local minimum actually. Who's right?

Thanks!

Comment: The correct term is differentiability. A function can be differentiable, not derivable.

Comment: It depends on the definition used, some books/authors define derivative only on open intervals, while some books/authors also define derivative at the end point using one-side limit.

Comment: You may want to read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability

Comment: The definition of minimum does not depend on the derivative, there is a minimum at $x=-1$.

Comment: @Wintermute both global and local?

Comment: yes, both. You can look up the standard definition in any precalc book.

Comment: @Maffred You can easily check the minima at $x=-1$. The minimum value of the function possible is $0$ i.e., at $x=-1$. Otherwise, for very large values of $x$, the function tends to $0$ but is never exact. So, $x=-1$ will be the local and the global minima

Comment: I was wrong, see [Can endpoints be local minimum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134265/can-endpoints-be-local-minimum)

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

For the second one: extremas are depends on the set that $f$ exists, and because there is no derivative (it is not differentiable) at $-1$ we need to check, in general extremas can appear at critical point and not differentiable points.

For the first one, their argument is non-sense, the limit does not exists (in this case it is $+\infty$) because it is not differentiable, how can they take the derivative of a point that only the right side limit exists for? By the definition of derivative we need to have 2 sided limit to takes the derivative of this point. So again you are right

---

As the comments pointed out we can define derivative with one side limit, so if this is the case then if the right side limit goes to $\infty$ they are right. So it depends on if you include one side derivative or not

Comment: Actually it is a matter of convention whether you allow a derivative to be defined at the edge of a domain. It's perfectly *legitimate* to consider the one-sided limit of $f((x+\epsilon)-f(x))/\epsilon$, although you may not want to.

Comment: @gj255 I see, I'll edit the answer to be better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I decide to look up Bartle's *Introduction to Real Analysis* for the definitions.

---

**(Definition of differentiability)**
[image: Definition of differentiability]

---

So according to the book, derivative at end points can indeed be defined as one-sided limit. Now
$$\begin{align*} 
\frac{f(x) - f(-1)}{x - (-1)} 
&= \frac{e^{-(x + 2)}\sqrt{x + 1} - e^{-(-1 + 2)}\sqrt{-1 + 1}}{x + 1} \\
&= \frac{e^{-(x + 2)}\sqrt{x + 1}}{x + 1}  \\
&= \frac{e^{-(x + 2)}}{\sqrt{x + 1}} \to +\infty \text{ as } x \to -1^+
\end{align*}$$
So I think your students can be considered correct for their first claim.

---

**(Definition of local extremum)**
[image: Definition of local extremum]

---

Again according to the book, a function is said to have a local minimum at $c$ if there is an open interval $I$ centered at $c$ such that $f(c) \le f(x)$ for all $x$ lying in the intersection of $I$ and the domain of $f$. Now since $f$ is strictly decreasing, $f(-1) \le f(x)$ for all $x$ lying in $(-2, 0) \cap [-1, +\infty)$. So I think your students are wrong for their second claim.