Are the endpoints of continuous functions always local extrema?
Thomas calculus suggests that local extrema might occur at the critical points and the endpoints of a continuous function on a closed interval. Are there cases where endpoints of a continuous function isn't a local extremum point? (Assume that local extrema are also global extrema)

Would you consider a constant function to have local extrema?

This depends on your definition of local extreme.  Some require it to be defined on both sides in order to be local.

@Aruralreader yes, I would consider it to have infinitely many local extrema at every point

The exact definition of local extremum matters: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134265/can-endpoints-be-local-minimum

Let
$$
f(x)=\cases{x\sin\left(\frac 1x\right) & $x \neq 0$ \\
0 & $x=0$}
$$
Then $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ but has no local extremum at $x=0$.

By using $x^{2n+1} \sin \frac{1}{x}$ we could even get a $\mathcal{C}^n$ counterexample (continuous $n$-th derivative).

@Adayah: And $e^{-\frac{1}{x}} \sin \frac{1}{x}$ makes it $C^\infty$!

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I wanted to outbid you with an analytic example, but it doesn't exist... Today you win again, but some day...

An alternative to jgd1729’s answer, to demonstrate a useful different technique: Think about what a counterexample would have to look like.  Without loss of generality, take $0$ as the endpoint in question, and try to make a counterexample $f$ continuous on $[0,\ldots]$.  Also WLOG fix the value at the endpoint as $f(0) = 0$. Both these choices are arbitrary — we could have chosen any values — but $0$ is always a good first guess for keeping calculations simple.
Now to prevent $0$ being a local maximum, $f$ must have positive values $f(x)$ for $x$ arbitrarily close to $0$.  So there must be some sequence $(a_i)$ with $a_i \to 0$, and with $f(a_i) > 0$ for all $i$.  By continuity, the values must also go to zero: $f(a_i) \to 0$. Similarly, to prevent $0$ being a local minimum, there must be a sequence $(b_i)$ going to $0$, and with all $f(b_i)$ negative, and with $f(b_i) \to 0$.
If we can build a continuous function with sequences like that, it’ll be a counterexample.  So first we need to pick two disjoint sequences going to $0$; the simplest choice is probably to take the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ and split it up into alternate terms, $a_i = \frac{1}{2i}$, $b_i = \frac{1}{2i+1}$.  Now we need to choose the values of $f$ on those sequences, positive/negative respectively and going to zero in either case.  A simple choice for that is $f(a_i) = a_i$, $f(b_i) = -b_i$.  Now we’ve got $f$ defined on all reciprocals $\frac{1}{n}$, by $f(\frac{1}{n}) = \pm \frac{1}{n}$ depending whether $n$ is even or odd; and between those, just “join the dots”, making the function zigzag between these values.
If you’re experienced enough, it’s “easy” to see that this is continuous and gives a counterexample.  If you haven’t worked through enough examples like this yet for it to seem obvious, then it’s a good exercise to draw a picture, check through the algebra, and convince yourself why it works.
For completeness, here’s a formula for the resulting function, using $(-1)^n$ to encode the alternating sign, and having done a little algebra to calculate that the slope of each join-the-dots line segment from $(\frac{1}{n},\pm \frac{1}{n})$ to $(\frac{1}{n+1}, \mp \frac{1}{n+1})$ is $\pm(2n+1)$:
$$
f(x)= \cases{
  (-1)^n \left(\textstyle \frac{1}{n} + (2n+1)(x-\frac{1}{n}) \right) & $x \in [\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$ (i.e. for $x \neq 0$, and taking $n := \lfloor{\frac{1}{x}}\rfloor$) \\ 0 & $x = 0$.}
$$
Plot on WolframAlpha — but do try picturing this yourself (at least mentally) before looking!
Note that this sort of approach is also a good way to find answers with cleaner formulas like jgd1729’s $x \sin \frac{1}{x}$. Having figured out that you need those two alternating sequences of positive and negative values as $x \to 0$, and the rough mental picture of the function going between them, then instead of just “joining the dots”, think through the toolbox of familiar functions to see how you could build a function looking like that.  You know $\sin$ alternates between positive and negative values suitably; you need to make the alternations come infinitely often as $x \to 0$, so give $\sin$ an argument like $\frac{1}{x}$ which diverges to $+\infty$ as $x \to 0$; and you need the overall function to go to $0$ as $x \to 0$, so multiply it by $x$ (or anything else which goes to $0$ but is strictly positive on $(0,1)$).

That's a very good description of how people actually find these examples.
